# Identifying the source of WM_QUERYENDSESSION and WM_ENDSESSION messages sent to my window

Tags: winapi

I'm currently working with WM_QUERYENDSESSION and WM_ENDSESSION messages in my application, both of which I know are sent to a window when the system is being shut down. Despite researching the documentation, I haven't found a method to determine the specific application that initiates the sending of these messages. My goal is to differentiate whether these messages originate from Winlogon.exe or other applications.

I'm handling these messages normally:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_QUERYENDSESSION:
        return TRUE;
    case WM_ENDSESSION:
        return TRUE;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

I haven't tried anything because I just couldn't find a way.

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: The question reads a lot like you are avoiding solving the *actual* problem. What's that problem anyway?

Comment: "*I haven't found a method to determine the specific application that initiates the sending of these messages*" - because no such method exists in the Win32 API. It does not identify the sender of window messages. If you really need this identification (why?), you will likely have to hook `SendMessage...()`, `ExitWindowsEx()`, `InitiateSystemShutdown/Ex()` etc directly in every running process.

Comment: @IInspectable I just don't want some applications to send me WM_QUERYENDSESSION and WM_ENDSESSION messages, I want them to be sent only when the system is actually being shut down.

Comment: @Nebula Can you edit your question (... I don't like other applications to send `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` using `SendMessage()` ...). I would have done this for you but I think in this case somebody would ask: "Why do you think an application will send these messages using `SendMessage()`?"

Comment: Applications are not supposed to send those messages at all. They're sent by the system when an application (or the user) initiates system shutdown.

Comment: Maybe you need [the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiatesystemshutdowna#remarks). Why do you differentiate whether these messages originate from Winlogon.exe or other applications?